# How to find the elements for below command in swift for XCUITEST

Tags: swift, xcode, xcuitest

```
 app.otherElements["the-lab-page"].children(matching: .image)["TheLab_Moon"]
```

How to find the loctor or identifier in XCUITEST Framework, it is single element
I used all types of combinations such as

```
 app.scrollViews.matching(identifier: "TheLab_Moon")


 app.otherElements.matching(identifier: "TheLab_Moon")
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you expecting this to match multiple elements? Strictly one? What’s the problem you are facing?

Comment: Only one  element i am trying to match ,  
Also I am not able to click on the particular elements , i used all types of elements such as other elements

Comment: Can you please provide the `XCUIApplication().debugDescription` of your application when in debug? It’s anyone’s guess what type of element this is.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the UI hierarchy of your application (this will be very important as you move forward with your testing), the least efficient way of finding an element with a particular identifier is the following:

`XCUIApplication().descendants(matching: .any).matching(NSPredicate(format: "identifier == 'TheLab_Moon'")).firstMatch`

Comment: Hey Mate , 
This is the below  hierarchy in the debug mode. 


`let app = XCUIApplication()

    let moonbackgroundimageImage = app.otherElements["the-lab-page"].children(matching: .image)["moonBackgroundImage"]`

Comment: That appears to be your test code, not the output of debugging. See my comment on your original question to return the app’s hierarchy.